# UITableView with overlay view updating the wrong index path

Tags: ios, uitableview

i have a tableview in Main Controller which has its custom cell that contains 3-4 button.. see screenshot [image]
when button getpressed it populate a small tableview , when i select row of new tableview it not works a i expected see screenshot [image]

Now issue is its setting selected value of new tableview to oldtableview same index

here's code :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"FollowUp";
    UITableViewCell *cell ;//= [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
     cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] ;
    if (tableView == tblScribedBy) {
        [cell.textLabel setText:[arrScribedBy objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        [cell.textLabel sizeToFit];
    }
    if (tableView == tblDropDown) {
        if ([btnCLicked isEqualToString:@"Cell"]) {
            [cell.textLabel setText:[totalRows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
            [cell.textLabel sizeToFit];
        }
        else if ([btnCLicked isEqualToString:@"Drop"]){
            [cell.textLabel setText:[arrFUDrop objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        }
    }
    if (tableView == tblView) {
        FUCellView * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];
        if (!cell)
        {
            [tblView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"FUCellView" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"myCell"];
            cell = [tblView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"myCell"];
            }
        [cell.btntfFUCell addTarget:self action:@selector(actionTfCellFU:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.btntfFUCell setTag:indexPath.row];
        [cell.btnDropFU addTarget:self action:@selector(actionDropFU:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.btnDropFU setTag:indexPath.row];

         return cell;
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    FUCellView *cell = (FUCellView *)[tblView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

     if ( tableView == tblScribedBy) {
       [self.btnScribedBy setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@",[arrScribedBy objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] forState:UIControlStateNormal  ];
         [tblScribedBy setHidden:TRUE];
    }

   else if (tableView == tblDropDown) {
        if ([btnCLicked isEqualToString:@"Cell"]) {
            [cell.tfFUCell setText:[totalRows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
        }
        else if ([btnCLicked isEqualToString:@"Drop"]){
            [cell.btnDropFU setTitle:[arrFUDrop objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
       [tblDropDown setHidden:YES];
    }

}

//----- Action for Buttons 
-(void)actionTfCellFU:(UIButton *)sender
{
    btnCLicked = @"Cell";
     [tblDropDown setHidden:FALSE];
    [tblDropDown reloadData];
}
-(void)actionDropFU:(UIButton *)sender
{
    btnCLicked = @"Drop";
    [tblDropDown setHidden:FALSE];
    [tblDropDown reloadData];

}
```

Comment: show the code which presents the second table view and your code for handling taps on both tables

Comment: deque cell like this  *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

Comment: Verify what are you doing in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` you are setting the title and text based on type of tableview.

Comment: @MuhammadNoman received this error  `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier MyCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard' `

Comment: use your identifer name instead of MyCell

Comment: you already have the code commented out. while dequeuing is more efficient, and you should change it, it won't solve your index problem

Comment: solution is tableView required to be registere , this line fixes issue [tblView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"FUCellView" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"myCell"];

Answer (score 0):

> `FUCellView *cell = (FUCellView *)[tblView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];`

This line is being used to get the cell to update, but it's using the index path selected on the second table view to get the target cell on the first table view. Hence you get an index error and the wrong cell is updated.

When `actionDropFU:` is called you need to determine a way of storing, as an instance variable, the index path of the cell which was selected. This is the index path on table 1 and is the one you want to use to update when setting the results of the selection from the second table later. In general you shouldn't be updating the cell directly, you should be updating your data model.

The best option for this is to not just add a target and selector to the buttons on your cells. Instead, subclass the cell and add properties to it so you can access them later when it is interacted with. The cell should be the target of the button clicks and it should call back to the view controller (as the cell delegate or target) when the buttons are tapped, passing the configured data (the index path).

Comment: before posting question i was using Typcasting like you mentioned above but nothing happend :(

Comment: ? I didn't mention typecasting ?